# Is $f$ is constant ? Yes/No

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Is the following statement  is true/false

let  $f$ be entire function  and if $\;\operatorname{Re}f(z) = <\operatorname{Im}f(z)$ then  $f$  is  constant .

My attempts : No   .   I take  $f(z) = z$  put $z = x +iy$    again  take $x=y$

now  we have $f(z) = y +iy$  but   $f(z)$ is not constant

Is it true?

Comment: The equality $\mathscr Re f(z)=\mathscr Im f(z)$ is meant to hold for all $z\in \mathbb C$, not just for the complex numbers of the form $x+ix$.

Comment: Note that $Im f(z) = Re (-i f(z))$, so you can rewrite the condition as $Re ((1+i)f(z)) = 0$. Can you continue?

Comment: @lulu here $\Re (f) = \Im (f) = x$    i  thinks not constant

Comment: Function $f(x+iy) = y+iy$ is not holomorphic.

Comment: Once again, the equality must hold for all $\mathbb C$, not just the points of the form $x+ix$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true. Let $g(z)=(1+i)f(z)$. Then, if $f(x+yi)=u(x,y)-v(x,y)i$, you have$$g(x+yi)=u(x,y)+v(x,y).$$Therefore, $\operatorname{Im}g(z)=0$ It is easy now to deduce from the Cauchy-Riemann equations that $g$ is constant. Since, $f=\frac g{1+i}$, $f$ is constant too.

Answer (score 2):

Cauchy - Riemann equation immediately tell you that all first  partial derivatives of the real and imaginary parts are  $0$, so $f$ is a constant.

Answer (score 1):

It is apparent that, in general, $\Re z\ne\Im z$.

The set $\{z\in\Bbb C\,:\, \Re z=\Im z\}$ has empty interior in $\Bbb C$, whereas holomorphic non-constant functions are open. So $f$ must be constant.